# sql server visualizar campo solo condicion

Tags: sql-server

Estimados: Pretendo realizar un critp de sql server mostrando para los campos 4,5,6 solamente cuando la suma total del campo sea mayor a cero, pero el sql me pide que lo realice por medio de  group by cuando yo no lo quiero agrupar

```
select  
campo1
,campo2
,campo3
,(CASE WHEN (SUM([campo4]) > '0') THEN [campo4] END) AS [campo4_mayor0]
,(CASE WHEN (SUM([campo5]) > '0') THEN [campo5] END) AS [campo5_mayor0]
,(CASE WHEN (SUM([campo6]) > '0') THEN [campo6] END) AS [campo6_mayor0]
from tabla1
```

Mi pretensión es que muestre solamente lo campos que al menos tiene un registro con al menos un registro con dato, son todos campos numéricos, en el caso que todos los registros seleccionados estén en 0 para el campo4 o campo5 o camp y no puedo usar el null porque esos campos cuando fueron creados se utilizó el default 0. en el caso que la suma de los datos del campo5 sea 0, la salida tiene que quedar de la siguiente manera:

campo1,campo2,campo3,campo4_mayor0,campo6_mayor0

gracias.

Comment: Y si no queres agrupar, que es lo que queres que haga el sum? que sume que cosas? porque sum, suma filas...

Comment: y el select muestra todos los campos que le digas.. no evita campos en base a condiciones.. no funciona asi SQL.. yo no termino de entender tu problema.. tal vez con un ejemplo sea mejor...

Comment: Hola gbianchi es que el ejemplo es un reducido del script dado que no tengo solamente 6 campos sino 200 y dependiendo de where la mayoría de esos camps ningun registro tenga un dato, entonces quería desarrollar una consulta que muestre solamente los campos que algún registro tenga algún dato, como todos son campos numéricos mi idea que sumar toda la columna y si es mayor a 0 entonces algún registros tenga un dato y en ese caso que se visualice el campo, actualmente el resultado del query lo paso a un excel y elimino la columna. Pero quiero ahorrar ese paso. Gracias

Comment: no. no vas a poder ahorrar ese paso.. porque sql no funciona asi. Podras desarrollar un procedimiento que haga eso.. pero no en un query simple.. el query simple tiene un select, y todos los campos que estan en el select se muestra.. y sum, funciona sumando toda una columna, pero necesita saber que filas sumar.. y para eso, necesita saber como agrupar. Lo que estas pidiendo, simplemente no se puede...